# Синтаксический разбор пословицы

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

На сайте Ask.fm задали вопрос.

Семь раз отмерь - один отрежь. Не понимаю, почему в ответах к упражнению указывают, что слова "семь раз" и "один" являются дополнениями... Это обстоятельства? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Ответ дали лингвисты сайта "Современный русский".

> На самом деле в этой пословице вопрос может быть задан двояко:
>   а) (что?) Семь раз отмерь - (что?) один отрежь.
>   б) (сколько?) Семь раз отмерь - (сколько?) один отрежь.
>   Оба варианта представляются корректными.

Мне показалось странным - выделять дополнение. Задал им повторный вопрос.

**Увидел ваш ответ и удивился. Вы считаете, в пословице“Семь раз отмерь - один отрежь'' действие сказуемого переходит на объект. Отмерь что? - семь раз.) Получается семь раз — это объект, действие сказуемого переходит на этот объект. Вам не кажется, что вопросы дополнения здесь немыслимы?**
Ответ.

> Нет, не кажется. Нормальная субстантивация (переход в существительное), вполне укладывается в смысл пословицы. Хотя, конечно, трактовка этих членов предложения как обстоятельств представляется нам приоритетной.

А как вы думаете, можно ли считать "семь раз" и "один"  дополнениями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Корректен один вариант:  **отмерь (сколько раз?) семь раз.** Количественный оборот обозначает **кратность действия и дополнением быть никак не может.**

Из словаря: **РАЗ**,  II. в зн. сущ. 1. (обычно со сл., обозначающими количество). Указывает **на кратность действия.** Несколько, много раз. Тысячу раз, бесконечное число раз слышал это (очень часто). Ни разу там не был (никогда).  **Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь (Посл.).**

**Объектом (дополнением)** является предмет, на которое направлено действие. К примеру, надо отмерить пять метров ткани. Семь раз ткань отмерь, а один раз отрежь.

Смысл пословицы, конечно, переносный, но от этого ничего не меняется. Например, семь раз о чем-то подумай, а потом один раз сделай.

**А ответ лингвистов действительно удивляет.** Как-то плохо представляется, как выглядит существительное "семь раз."

Comment: Да, я тоже никак не могу понять их логику.

Comment: Я ответил на Мете.